# PeeWee PostgreSQL Database creation: does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm attempting to create a PostgreSQL database using `PeeWee`. Upon connecting I get the following error:

> File "peewee_test.py", line 44, in 
>      psql_db.connect()
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3602, in connect
>      self.initialize_connection(self._local.conn)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3514, in **exit**
>      reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3600, in connect
>      **self.connect_kwargs)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\playhouse\postgres_ext.py", line 385, in _connect
>      conn = super(PostgresqlExtDatabase, self)._connect(database, **kwargs)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3990, in _connect
>      conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database, **kwargs)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2__init__.py", line 164, in connect
>      conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
>   peewee.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test" does not exist

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.postgres_ext import PostgresqlExtDatabase

psql_db = PostgresqlExtDatabase(
    'test',  # Required by Peewee.
    user='xxxxx',  # Will be passed directly to psycopg2.
    password='xxxxx',  # Ditto.
    host='',  # Ditto.
    port='5432'
)

psql_db.connect() # error occurs here

psql_db.create_tables([Person, Pet])
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the database `test` configured and the current user/password/host you are using have privileges to access this database?

Comment: @Dekel I know my username and pass are correct. However the PostgreSQL db doesn't exist. I thought PeeWee would create it for me? I am running my script locally and expect/want my db to be local aswell

Comment: Ok my silly mistake. Once I create the database everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Peewee wont create the database for you, you need to first connect to the database with psql shell for example and admin user access `psql --host HOST  --port 5432 --username YOUR_USER -W -d postgres` and run `CREATE DATABASE test;`

Postgres has also a helper `createdb` executable:

```
createdb my_db
```